# Three.js - Generating font shapes with lower fineness (divisions parameter is not used?)

Tags: fonts, three.js

In the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Font) of the Font class it is said that you can handle the fineness of the generated text shape via the "divisions" parameter. However, when i look at the [implementation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/core/Font.js) i see that this parameter is handed over to several functions but never really used in the generation process. When calling the "generateShapes" function with different values for this parameter, the fineness of the text shape also doesn't change.

Do i miss something here? Or is this functionality just not implemented yet?

Comment: Looks like the `divisions` parameter is actually obsolete. A subdivision of the shape is done in `ExtrudeGeometry` when sampling the shape.

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fineness of the geometry based on a given shape is controlled via `Shape.extractPoints()`. The `divisions` parameter is the rest of a former implementation of `Font` which was removed with the following commit:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/4e4cc802133949c8005f1774773cb967f6fe2528#diff-ecc50189f09945f8d8b1d5ea9ba1ad6e